# embed javascript to a jasper report pdf?

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to embed a javascript function into a pdf file generated by jasper.
it comes to my mind because I want to make the pdf file auto open printing dialog.
after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript) and tried [this example](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php) I want to do the same.

but I use iReport designer to create my pdf templates and then export using struts actions, any idea how to embed javascript with ireport?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.javascript`*** property.

The information about this property is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.javascript).

Comment: That helped me to know what to search!. completing the answer I added this line to make it work: exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");