# Open PDF link with print window active

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, hyperlink

I'm linking to a PDF, but instead of it simply downloading or opening within browser, I'd like it to open with the print window open - ready for the user to print.

How do I go about that please? Or is it all based on your browser settings so impossible to force?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of this question (which has good answers, too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript/2495430

Answer (score 2):

One solution (short version):

1. Open an iframe with the pdf in it, setting the width and height to 0 so that it is not shown
2. Inject some javascript into the PDF-file
3. When the javascript is run because the PDF is displayed, the print dialoge from adobe will be displayed.

Long version and implementation code is available from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196541/Printing-a-PDF-from-a-web-page) codeproject.com-post

Answer (score 1):

As a refinement to the method referenced Sindre, I found that you can simply set the openAction of the document to be the pre-defined PRINTDIALOG action.  Using iText (in Java), it's simply:

```
writer.SetOpenAction( new PdfAction( PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG ));
```

This avoids using JavaScript, which could be disabled as a security measure.