# php print option to newly opened page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following link

```
<a href="test.pdf" target="_blank">test.pdf</a>
```

By clicking on this link, the file will be opened in a new window. As soon  as the PDF is opened in new window , I want to open the print Dialog box (to print the pdf content). Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript

Comment: @Yan: Don't you mean [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2495430/342886)?