# Print a pdf with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I need to print a .pdf file (I generate it with jasperReport and I save it on a server) when I click on a print.gif button.
Now I found this solution that works for Firefox but not for IE!

```
function printPdf(){    
  var url= document.getElementById('_url').value;    
  newwindow=window.open();  
  newdocument=newwindow.document;   
  newdocument.write('<embed   type="application/pdf"  src="'+url+'"
       id="pdfDocument"   height="100%" width="100%" ></embed> <SCR'+'IPT
       LANGUAGE="JavaScript">window.print();window.close();</SCR'+'IPT>'); 
}
```

I tried also `document.close();` `window.focus();` `window.print();` `window.close();`, but they didn't work!

I read a lot of topics, but I can't find a solution for this issue!

Comment: If you want to print the .pdf on paper, using a real printer, then it might be better to [check here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/) for different plugins and solutions on how to print out a pdf via jQuery. Additionally, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript) on Stack Overflow could help. Good luck!

Comment: @Thara - this sounds like a good answer.  I'd vote it up.

Comment: I tried with the tutorial that you linked. But I always print a blank page!

Comment: PrintJs so good http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 4):

Create a `iframe` in html:

```
<iframe id="pdf-iframe">
```

Then change the `src` of that `iframe` and `on load`, print it.

```
$('#pdf-iframe').attr("src", pdf_url).load(function(){
    document.getElementById('pdf-iframe').contentWindow.print();
});
```

Comment: This tirggers the following error:

"blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Problem is that the content is not loaded yet?
I had the same issue in IE8. I had to save the document, reopen it, print, and close the window again.