# Print PDF in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, printing, pdf-generation

How to print a PDF in Firefox?

This function works in Chrome but not in Firefox

```
function print_pdf(url){
    var id = 'iframe', html = '<iframe id="'+id+'" src="'+url+'" style="display:none"></iframe>';
    $('#main').append(html);
    $('#'+id).load(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.print();
    }
}
```

## error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "print"
```

Comment: It doesn't just work or it shows some error? Can you provide a jsfiddle for us to take a look?

Comment: The printed page is empty.. Like an empty webpage with URL in the header and date in the footer

Comment: TypeError: document.frames is undefined

Comment: I just noticed, you have `style="display:none"`. If the item is not showing, it won't get printed. Think as if the printed page is a screen. If there is no item showing, it won't get printed.

Comment: the DOM variable/object is undefined.

Comment: I'd try wrapping a setTimeout around the "print()".. ala..

setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.print();}, 2000);

Comment: Hi @clarkk, you wan't to open the page preview or just send to the printer?

Comment: I just want to send to the printer..

Comment: Why can't you use display:block and just position the iframe absolutely in some negative coordinates?

Comment: @clarkk check this out, it may help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing

Comment: In 2024 this code works in firefox.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Firefox: Permission denied to access property "print"

This is a [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444). Locally it can be disabled by going to `about:config` and set the property of `pdfjs.disabled` to true. Only possible workaround is to use a server-side script and modify the pdf. Using php you could use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) and embed [extensions](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php) to implement js (inclunding the `print()` function) or simply convert the pdf to an image, return the url and print it. You could use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to modify the existing pdf. I will give you an example on how I got it to work with PHP.

**Generating a PDF file with inline javascript (autoprint) using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) and [PDF_JS](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php)**

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

class PDF_JavaScript extends FPDI {

    var $javascript;
    var $n_js;

    function IncludeJS($script) {
        $this->javascript=$script;
    }

    function _putjavascript() {
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->n_js=$this->n;
        $this->_out('<<');
        $this->_out('/Names [(EmbeddedJS) '.($this->n+1).' 0 R]');
        $this->_out('>>');
        $this->_out('endobj');
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->_out('<<');
        $this->_out('/S /JavaScript');
        $this->_out('/JS '.$this->_textstring($this->javascript));
        $this->_out('>>');
        $this->_out('endobj');
    }

    function _putresources() {
        parent::_putresources();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_putjavascript();
        }
    }

    function _putcatalog() {
        parent::_putcatalog();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_out('/Names <</JavaScript '.($this->n_js).' 0 R>>');
        }
    }
}

class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
    function AutoPrint($dialog=false)
    {
        //Open the print dialog or start printing immediately on the standard printer
        $param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
        $script="print($param);";
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }

    function AutoPrintToPrinter($server, $printer, $dialog=false)
    {
        $script = "document.contentWindow.print();";
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }
}

$pdf=new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pdf->setSourceFile("mozilla.pdf");
//Open the print dialog
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);
$pdf->AutoPrint(true);
$pdf->Output('generated.pdf', 'F');
```

Now you can simply append the generated pdf to your page and the included javascript will call the `print()` function. You do not even have to call it manually anymore. However, in firefox this will only work with `visibility: hidden` and not with `display: none`.

```
function print_pdf(url){
    var iFrameJQueryObject = $('<iframe id="iframe" src="'+url+'" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>');
    $('#foo').append(iFrameJQueryObject);
}
print_pdf('mozilla_generated.pdf');
```

---

### Chrome: Security Error (cross-origin)

The pdf should be located at the same host. Firefox was okay with other domains in my tests, but chrome gave me cross-origin errors.

---

### Firefox: Printed page includes `about:blank` only

You will get an empty page in firefox ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrp6sd6h/1/)), because it will print the iframe before it has loaded any content. Mentioned methods like `$(document).onload()` won't help, since they only wait for the DOM to load and `setTimeout()` can still result in errors, since you do not know how long it takes the iFrame to load.

You can simply resolve this issue by using jQuery's `load()`. ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) This will give you the possibility to use a callback function as parameter.

> if a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and `this` is set to each DOM element in turn.

**Code Example 1**

```
function print_pdf(url){
    var id = 'iframe', html = '<iframe id="'+id+'" src="'+url+'" style="display:none"></iframe>';
    $('body').append(html);
    // wait for the iFrame to fully load and call the print() function afterwards
    $('#' + id).load(function () {
        document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.print();
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could directly create an jQuery object and use jQuery's `on()` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) to attach any event handler.

**Code Example 2** (**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrp6sd6h/2/)**)

```
function print_pdf(url){
    var iFrameJQueryObject = $('<iframe id="iframe" src="'+url+'" style="display:none"></iframe>');
    $('body').append(iFrameJQueryObject);
    iFrameJQueryObject.on('load', function(){
        $(this).get(0).contentWindow.print();
    });
}
```

Comment: You would be better off creating the iframe as a JS object instead of as a string. That way you can add event handlers, such as onload, to it before you add it to the page.

Comment: @HoschNok Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate approach at solution ?

Comment: jsfiddle will have x-origin problems when using iframes, so this is inconvenient. I still got it to work, by using just the same url as url.

Comment: I get this error in Firefox: `Error: Permission denied to access property "print"`

Comment: In the jsfiddle too? only on localhost? make sure you use same protocol like http:// and not file://

Comment: If you put an actual PDF file into the function it does not work http://jsfiddle.net/zrp6sd6h/4/ `Error: Permission denied to access property "print"`

Comment: - and i think it has something to do with Firefox uses its own javascript PDF viewer `pdf.js`

Comment: which os/browser version are you using? I am currently using Ubuntu.

Comment: I have posted a working workaround in PHP. Seems pretty much overkill, you might consider using another approach such as simply downloading/open the PDF and let the user print it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Edit, Updated

Try using `window.onload` event , `document.createElement()` , `onload` event , `setTimeout()` with `duration` set to `2000` , setting `src` of `iframe` after appending element to `document`

```
window.onload = function() {
    function print_pdf(url){
        var id = "iframe", frame = document.createElement("iframe");
        frame.setAttribute("id", id);
        frame.setAttribute("width", "800px");
        frame.setAttribute("height", "600px");
        frame.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
        frame.setAttribute("name", "printframe");
        document.body.appendChild(frame);
        frame.onload = function() {
          this.requestFullScreen = this.mozRequestFullScreen 
                                   || this.webkitRequestFullScreen;
          this.requestFullScreen();
          setTimeout(function() {
            print()
          },2000)
        }
        frame.setAttribute("src", url);
    }
    print_pdf("http://zeitreisen.zeit.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/pdftest2.pdf");
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mHBNmc5mdM0YJRwRbYif?p=preview

Comment: The code triggers an `alert` before the print dialog comes up saying: pdf.js is not fully loaded

Comment: @clarkk _"The code triggers an alert before the print dialog comes"_ Adjust individual firefox browser print preferences for default action at print ? _"and the PDF has to be hidden "_ Not certain interpret "PDF has to be hidden" ? Load iframe with `display:none` adjust `iframe` to `display:block` before calling `.print()`? If `iframe` is loaded and `.print()` called immediately print window should display `iframe` contents and have immediate focus before parent `window` regains focus when print dialog canceled or documented printed to filesystem.

Comment: @clarkk Can a server side solution be used to meet requirement ?

Comment: I would prefer a javascript solution.. But show me what you had in mind

Comment: @clarkk See updated post , added `window.onload` event , added `duration` of `2000` to `setTimeout`. Tried at nightly, chromium ; appear to return same results at each.

Comment: I tried this and it returns an empty page in chrome on my machine.

Comment: @HorstJahns _" tried this and it returns an empty page in chrome on my machine."_ Were plugins allowed for page ?

Comment: This appears to be printing the iframe rather than the pdf. That means the pdf will get cut off if it's larger than the dimensions of the iframe. Also, triggering the print dialog after some arbitrary timeout will be very unreliable since the pdf's load time could vary greatly depending on its size, the user's connection speed, system resources, etc.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo There is not actually a `.pdf` file displayed , but a rendering of `.pdf` file as `html` by either firefox or chrome `js` plugin. Yes, `setTimeout` is not optimal solution , without adjusting `js` that renders `.pdf` as `html` ; which appears slightly different for each browser

Comment: @guest271314 My point was that you're printing the iframe (or rather, its parent window) instead of the iframe's content. Doesn't matter if the content is html or pdf; if it's larger than the iframe, it will get cut off. That's the consequence of using `print()` instead of `frame.documentWindow.print()`.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo _"My point was that you're printing the iframe (or rather, its parent window) instead of the iframe's content."_ , _"That's the consequence of using print() instead of frame.documentWindow.print()"_ Good points. Approach is to avoid `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://run.plnkr.co" from accessing a frame with origin "http://zeitreisen.zeit.de". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`  Can dynamically adjust `width`, `height` of `iframe`, or `parent`  to address possible clipping of print job.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't think Firefox allows JavaScript to access most of the properties and methods of the iframe's contentWindow or any of its descendants, so you probably couldn't use JS to determine the pdf's size. If you could measure it server-side somehow, then you'd be in business.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Since no `.pdf` is actually displayed at `document` , `html` rendering of `.pdf` could be adjusted, or "resized" based on screen. Used arbitrary `width`, `height` at `html` at post , and attempted to incorporate `requestFullScreen` to cover viewport of user. Could determine user screen size before creating or setting `iframe` `src` , then render `iframe` to fill `viewport` without clipping document. This is , perhaps, fine-tuning portion ; beyond scope of Question. Solution at post printed `window` at chrome / chromium , firefox ; have not yet tried at mac or opera

Comment: @guest271314 Were you actually able to reference and manipulate elements of the converted pdf via JavaScript? If you can do that, then you might as well just do a simulated `click()` on the pdf viewer's built-in print button, or just run its `onclick` function directly. In my testing, though, Firefox denied access to *everything* within the iframe once the pdf was loaded. If you have a workaround, you should incorporate it into your post. Your current solution prints the iframe's parent window, which isn't the same thing as printing its content document.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo _"Were you actually able to reference and manipulate elements of the converted pdf via JavaScript?"_ This is more involved. If open plnkr at firefox, open `console` and navigate to `Script` tab, should observe that `pdf.js` is loaded. This can also be viewed at `css` tab as well, where `viewer.css` is listed as `<System>`.  This presents at least two challenges; 1) accessing cross-domain `iframe` , 2) accessing `<System>` resources. Source of both `viewer.css` and `pdf.js` can be viewed at GitHub. Firefox and chrome appear to implement rendering `.pdf` documents differently.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Stopped short of modifying `pdf.js` for this specific Question, as users at large browsers' would not have same resources available natively.  Simplest approach would be to use `pdftohtml` or similar library to render `.pdf` as `html` , adjust `style` as necessary - without browser attempting to render `.pdf`. That is, save `.pdf` locally, render to `html` , adjust styles , when user visits page display `.pdf` as `html` without browser plugins automatically trying to load plugin and render `.pdf` as `html`

Answer (score 2):

PDFs have Javascript support. I needed to have auto print capabilities when a PHP-generated PDF was created and I was able to use FPDF to get it to work:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php

Answer (score 0):

@clarkk i would recommend to use something more powerful which has been covered from many people my suggestion is to use http://pdfmake.org/#/ .

I have use this pdfmake in my datatables and it works absolutely perfect. Keep in mind if you print more then 10 000 rows from tables or something it run out the memory of the browser :)

Comment: Creating the PDF on client side is not an option.. Then you have to maintain both the serverside PDF genereator and the client side PDF generator.. The client side PDF generator is the primary

Comment: Yes you are right but in little information i can tell you that it is super fast. Also it relay on html5 and when you want a cross browser compatibility is great, Also it is a free library and you do not support anything everything is done by the guys you need only to replace the library so it is not a big deal of support.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use this for a while, but this what I was used to do to print pdf's from an iframe...

```
function printfile() {
    window.frames['objAdobePrint'].focus();
    window.frames['objAdobePrint'].print();
}

<iframe src="urlOfPdf" name="objAdobePrint" id="objAdobePrint"></iframe>
<button onclick="printfile();">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement print function without create new iframe (only with css) to prevent security problems:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.setAttribute("media", "print"); //style.setAttribute("media", "screen,print");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
document.head.appendChild(style);
var width = $("#printDiv").width();
var height = $("#printDiv").height();
style.sheet.insertRule("body { width: 210mm !important, height: 25.4mm !important; visibility: hidden; }", 0);
style.sheet.insertRule("#printDiv { visibility: visible; position: fixed !important;top: 5px;  left: 5px; width:" + width + "px;height:" + height + ";  page-break-after: avoid;}", 0);

window.focus();
window.print(true);
style.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

[Print a pdf with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400508/print-a-pdf-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Create a iframe in html:

```
<iframe id="pdf-iframe">
```

Then change the src of that iframe and on load, print it:

```
$('#pdf-iframe').attr("src", pdf_url).load(function(){
    document.getElementById('pdf-iframe').contentWindow.print();
});
```

Or, you might want to try https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: `contentWindow.print()` does not work in Firefox because it returns `Error: Permission denied to access property "print"`

Comment: It is because of your firefox default pdfjs config. It is a known issue. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444 Please try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011799/firefox-19-print-pdf-from-javascript#answer-21500997 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011799/firefox-19-print-pdf-from-javascript#answer-25490208