# How to Print Pdf in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

I have URL of pdf file for exa url is "test.example.com/incoice/1/download?auth_token="some_token", when I visit this url, url will show me PDF in browser.

Now I want to open this pdf with print function, I mean user do not have to press `CTRL+P` I want to do this from my side.

I tried iframe but it gives me error of cross origin.
This is demo code which i used

```
//first try

 let _printIframe;
var iframe = _printIframe;
if (!_printIframe) {
    iframe = _printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.id  = "printf";
    iframe.name = "printf";
    iframe.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }, 1);
    };
  }

// second try 
   // SRC of pdf
iframe.src = "Some API URl " + "/download?access_token=" + 
this.authenticationService.currentTokenDetails.access_token;
let url = iframe.src + "&output=embed";

window.frames["printf"].focus();
window.frames["printf"].print();
var newWin = window.frames["printf"];
newWin.document.write('<body onload="window.print()">dddd</body>');
newWin.document.close();
```

I created a demo in plunker for print pdf. http://embed.plnkr.co/WvaB9HZicxK6tC3OAUEw/ In this plunker i open pdf in new window but i want to directly print that pdf. how can i do that ?

Any suggestion will be appreciate, and you can correct if I am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So here I got the solution for my problem
In my situation my API was returning `binary data of pdf`, and browser did not print that binary data into window.print, so for this first I convert `binary` data in `blob` data and then create `Iframe` for print
Following is code for it.

```
const url = request URL // e.g localhost:3000 + "/download?access_token=" + "sample access token";
this.http.get(url, {
  responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
}).subscribe(
  (response) => { // download file
    var blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
      iframe.src = blobUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
});
```

Here you go!!
I hope this can help anyone have this problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this

Comment: It is important to note, this doesn't work on Microsoft browsers (IE and Edge).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685552/print-pdf-report-in-ie-11) is a question on how to solve that issue. If you simply want to open on save the blob you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11)

Comment: Thanks, Is it any solution to print without print dialog box?

Comment: I think this will not work with firefox. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254679/print-pdf-in-firefox

Comment: how can I print multiple files in one click

Answer (score 3):

The previous solution may cause some security issues in newer browsers so we need to use the DOMSanitizer to make it a safe resource.

```js
export class PrintPdfService {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  printPdf(res) {
    const pdf = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(blobUrl));
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
  }
}
```

[Angular DOMSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Answer (score -3):

Look at https://github.com/devintyler/real-time-angular2/tree/master/plugin/print-pdf

simple and nice implementation.

Comment: Okay i will try it

Comment: i tried it . but didn't work for me. Can you create a demo plunker ?