# Print PDF Report in IE 11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

As the tile suggest, I am trying to print a PDF report specifically on IE 11. The following snippet of code works will in chrome, but when it come to IE11, all hell breaks loose; nothing works. To give you a background, I am developing Angular 5 reporting application. Here the user can view, download and print the report. I was able to achieve all the above functionalities except for printing on IE 11!

```
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
      iframe.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Cant find the exact issue without the URL to debug. One thing to try though. Use someother iframe variable name as its a keyword. May be IE messes up with this ambiguity, which Chrome handles it well.

Comment: Thanks Anand for your input, by sadly that didn't help.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: You have to host a test page for the community to debug and help.

Comment: any update on this question??

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth its not possible. On IE, you can only download the report.

Comment: @user2697452 please check my answer. it worked fo rme

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get print on IE, this is a slight hack I learned, it works.

```
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  iframe.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.load = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  iframe.focus();
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
   }); 
  };
```

with this hack, it worked on the latest IE

Comment: @Ramesh_D Yes, it did work. This code is in production.

Comment: for ie11, we cannot set blob data uri in "iframe.src". (From my research).

This code will work for latest all browsers. but not on ie11.