# How to Print Excel file in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Bellow I have attach my code.

I am trying to print the excel file using angular with out user pressing the ctrl+P. I did found the relevant code in below link and I am able to open the print popup but with just blank white page with no content on it. Thank you for you suggestions in advance.

```
printListXcel() {
  this.listService.getListExcel(this.ListId).subscribe(data => {
  const blobData = new Blob([data], { 
type:'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
   const blobUrl =  URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
   const iframexcel = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframexcel.style.display = 'none';
   iframexcel.src = blobUrl;
   document.body.appendChild(iframexcel);
   iframexcel.contentWindow.print();
});
}
```

[how to print pdf in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244148/how-to-print-pdf-in-angular-2)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome.