# How to print a pdf file on page load, using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a web application.

On a page load,i need send a external pdf file to print .How it can make it work.

I have searched a lot , but couldn't find a working solution .

Anybody have an idea about this please??

Comment: Can you mention the plugin name

Comment: Try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin [**This**](http://trevordavis.net/play/javascript-print-link/)

On document.ready use

```
$('ul#tools li.print a').trigger('click');
```

Try on console first.

Comment: No, that won't  for me.I need to print an external pdf file like test.pdf file

Comment: @Linto , then please specify properly in question

Comment: @ jQuery Angry Bird, Modified my question