# Rails print button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I place a button in my dashboard to print the contents of an item (let's say a html/pdf offer)?

When I do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Print', "/detalii-oferta/#{offer.offer_token}.pdf", :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

it takes the dashboard view into printing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6010113/1801147

Comment: Thanks and sorry for duplication.