# Print generated pdf file

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using fpdf to generate my invoice.

so the problem is whenever I open the link the file downloading automatically ..

I want to print the file when I click on the link...

I have tried `onclick="print();"`

but its printing the HTML page

the link :

```
echo "<th><a href='invoices.php?source=print_invoice&inv_id=$inv_id'>print</a></th>";
```

I also tried using `I` in $pdf->Output('invoice.pdf','I');

not working also ...

edit :

I tried this [Script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php)
But is not working

I get these two errors :

> Notice: Constant FPDF_VERSION already defined
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class FPDF

Is it possible to display the print dialog with the pdf from the link when I click the print?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a PDF file's print dialog be opened with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem at my job. My solution was to open a new window with print options and attach the html content.

your html

```
<button type="button" onclick="foo();">Click to print </button>
```

Your javascript

```
function foo(){
$.get( 'your_server_pdf_generator.php', {anyvariable: "value" },  function 
(returnedHtml) 
  {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write(returnedHtml);
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;} );}
```